# Why java.rmi.server.RemoteServer.getClientHost() get 127.0.0.1

Tags: java

When i use RemoteServer.getClientHost(),i get 127.0.0.1 on red hat,but on windows,i get my local ip 192.168.1.15,does linux needs the different method?
With the same code:

```
  String chost = getClientHost();// 客户端主机
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();
                strb.append("客户端主机:").append(chost).append(",用户名:").append(username);
                logger.debug(strb.toString());
            }
            boolean login = rmiImpl.serverLogin(chost, username, password);
            System.out.println(chost+"........"+username+"......."+password);
            if (!login) {
                logger.debug("登录失败...");
                throw new LoginException();
            }
```

console appears:127.0.0.1........TestWebServer.......123456

my english is not very well!

Comment: Probably you're testing on localhost, which IP is 127.0.0.1. [Explanatory image](http://a.tgcdn.net/images/products/zoom/noplacelike_mat.jpg)

Comment: But why i get different ip in different OS by the same code

Answer (score 2):

> But why i get different ip in different OS by the same code

The short answer is that it is a configuration problem / issue.

---

The IP address you get from that call depends on three things:

- how the client requested the connection to your server,
- how the request was mapped to an IP address, and
- whether the request can to your server directly, or via a proxy / reverse proxy.

Without more information we can't be sure but it could be this:

- The Linux machine has been configured to map "localhost" to the IP address `127.0.0.1` which is an address for the "loopback" network interface.  (That's not a physical network interface ...)
- The Windows machine has been configured to map "localhost" to the host's "real" IP address.

Mapping "localhost" to the 127.0.0.1 IP address is normal practice for Linux / UNIX machines, going back (at least) to the 4.x bsd UNIX days.  I'm not sure what constitutes normal practice on Windows, but apparently "localhost" is not configured at all on some versions of Windows (out of the box).  And it is plausible that someone has configured it ... in an inadvisable way.

(I haven't talked about the issue with proxies.  But if that's what the problem is, there's little chance you can do anything about it.)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running both OS on the same machine.

Could be so that the unix system lists the loopback interface first and therefore that address is returned, when windows however lists the ethernet interface first and returns the ethernet adress.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on @StephenC's answer:

1. `getClientHost()` returns the remote socket address of the incoming socket.
2. That value depends on what IP address the client automatically bound its outgoing socket to when connecting to the server.
3. That in turn depends on the IP route from the client to the server.
4. That in turn depends on what the client is trying to connect to.
5. The client will bind itself to whichever of its outgoing IP addresses has the cheapest route to the target.
6. And *that* in turn depends on whether the client saw the server's address as 127.0.0.1 or as an external IP address.
7. Which in turn depends on the DNS or etc/hosts file at the client.

You can ignore the effect of RMI proxies unless you've bought one from me ;-) or unless you're using the ghastly HTTP tunneling option.

Comment: In point 2, the "client" is really the last hop in the proxy / reverse proxy chain.  And even then, there is the possibility of that IP address being "messed with" in the network layers (e.g. NAT).  You simply cannot guarantee to see the IP address of (say) the user's browser.